# MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChange called twice

Tags: ios, swift, mpmusicplayercontroller

I am using `let player = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer()` as a player.

This is the whole code needed to replicate this issue:

```
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let player = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer()
        player.beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications()
        player.setQueueWithStoreIDs(["401187194"])
        player.play()


        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(now_playing_item_changed),
            name: NSNotification.Name.MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChange,
            object: nil)
    }

    func now_playing_item_changed(_ notification: Notification){
        NSLog("CALLED")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Just start a new one view swift app and fill the ViewController.swift file with the above code. It only works if you have an apple music subscription. You can probably exchange `setQueueWithStoreIDs` for something else to get it to work without owning apple music.

Apart from the problem, that the notification gets thrown 2-4 times when I start up the app, every time a song ends or changes it is thrown twice.

And I don't know a proper way to differentiate between those two calls without some hacky coding (like counting the calls etc.)

Does anyone know why these notifications get thrown twice or how to differentiate those in a sane way?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't call the piece of code that add the observer too many times? For instance, try to log the address of that notification, and check if it's the same object. If it's the same object, you clearly added that many times the observer

Comment: I am definetely calling the addObserver() function only once. I also checked the objects address and its different every time. Even `notification.userInfo` which contains the PersistentIDKey of the currently playing song is the same.

Comment: Just one of the quirks of MusicPlayer. I used a workaround many years ago for this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6277067/558575

Comment: I guess lastModifiedData is a property of MPMediaLibrary. How would I access that through a notification whose object is a MPMusicPlayerController?